# Why can we assume the other endpoint of this hyperbolic line lies after $x=1$? (Anderson's Hyberbolic Geometry Prop. 3.22)

Tags: proof-explanation, hyperbolic-geometry, mobius-transformation

I'm reading through *James Anderson*'s *Hyberbolic Geometry*. Proposition 3.22 and the first step of it's proof is as follows

> **Proposition 3.22:** Let $l_0$ and $l_1$ be ultraparallel hyperbolic lines in $\mathbb{H}$. Then $d_{\mathbb{H}}(l_0, l_1)>0$.
>
> **Proof:** Again, by making use of the triple transitivity of $\mathrm{Mob}(\mathbb{H})$ on $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$, we may assume
> that the endpoints at infinity of $l_0$ are 0 and $\infty$, and that the endpoints at
> infinity of $l_1$ are $1$ and $x > 1$. [Continues]....

I know that triple transitivity of $\mathrm{Mob}(\mathbb{H})$ on $ \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ allows us to send three of the four endpoints to $0,1,\infty$ as such. But I thought that doing so, we will not have any control on the image of the fourth endpoint; it could be anywhere other than those three images. How can we assume that for the image $x$ of the fourth endpoint, we have $x>1$?

I suspect that otherwise we could act some element of $\mathrm{Mob}(\mathbb{H})$ to get the desired result; But I can't see such element of the group. And also I suspected that conformality of elements of $\mathrm{Mob}(\mathbb{H})$ automatically forces $x$ to be greater than $1$, but I can't tell.

**Edits:** As it seem's that $\mathrm{Mob}(\mathbb{H})$ is not something generally agreed upon, here it means the group of transformations of either of the two following forms:

1. $ \frac{az+b}{cz+d} $ where $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$ and $ad-bc=1$.
2. $ \frac{a\bar{z}+b}{c\bar{z}+d} $ where $a,b,c,d \in i \mathbb{R}$ and $ad-bc = 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the four points in cyclic order as $a,b,c,d$, where $a,b$ are the endpoints of $l_0$ and $c,d$ are the endpoints of $l_1$. Here by "cyclic order" I mean that one of four inequalities holds:

- $a<b<c<d$ (allowing $d=\infty$);
- $b<c<d<a$ (allowing $a=\infty$);
- $c<d<a<b$ (allowing $b=\infty$);
- $d<a<b<c$ (allowing $c=\infty$).

Now choose a Möbius transformation in $\text{PSL}_2(\mathbb R)$ that has the effect $a \mapsto a'=\infty$, $b \mapsto b'=0$, $c \mapsto c'=1$. Because elements of $\text{PSL}_2(\mathbb R)$ respect cyclic order, this forces $d \mapsto d' \in (1,+\infty)$.

Comment: Is there a typo in "$d' \in (0, + \infty)$" and shouldn't that be "$ d' \in (1,\infty)$"?
And that's interesting; I didn't know about cyclic order and this property of mobius transformations; Could you please tell if the following is a correct restatement of your answer?: Looking at $\overline{\mathbb{C}}$ as Riemann's sphere, the endpoints are on the circle $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ and therefore posses some cyclic order. Take one of the elements in the cycle and map it to $\infty$, next one to $0$ and the next to $1$; regarding the order-preserving property, the result follows.

Comment: Oh I think I'm not quite following; if $m$ is some mobius transformation which has the effect $0 \mapsto 0$, $1 \mapsto \infty$ and $ \infty \mapsto 1$ (by triple transitivity such $m$ exists), then $m$ is not preserving order. Am I getting cyclic order wrong?

Comment: I presume that $\text{Mob}(\mathbb H)$ refers to the action of $\text{PSL}_2(\mathbb R)$ on the upper half plane by fractional linear transformations (this presumption could be wrong, I suppose...). In that case the action on $\mathbb R \cup \{\infty\}$ is triply transitive **only** on the set of positively oriented triples in $\mathbb R \cup \{\infty\}$. The triples $(0,1,\infty)$ and $(0,\infty,1)$ are oppositely oriented, and there does not exist an element of $\text{PSL}_2(\mathbb R)$ taking one to the other.

Comment: I see; I added the book's definition of $\mathrm{Mob}(\mathbb{H})$. It contained some other fractional linear transformations too. So everything is fine, Thank you. Just could please say some words about why elements of $\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ preserve cyclic order? I couldn't achieve it by my own or find it online.

Comment: Okay, so yes, the second kind with $\bar z$ reverse the cyclic ordering of $\mathbb R \cup \{\infty\}$. The first kind with $z$ are just the ones in $\text{PSL}_2(\mathbb R)$, which preserve the cyclic ordering. That is easy to prove using calculus: the derivative with respect to $z \in \mathbb R$ is positive in $\text{PSL}_2(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: Uh yes, of course. Thank you professor.